# El conjunto de resultados no tiene fila actual, campos nulos

Tags: java, sql

La conexión a la base de datos funciona perfectamente (SQLSERVER) pero,
tengo el siguiente código que no está devolviendo ningún campo definido en la base de datos:

Has intentado seteando manualmente dos valores cualesquiera existentes exactamente como están registrados en la BD en el parámetros del *preparedStatement* para ver si  así me devuelve resultados pero tengo el mismo problema.

Desde ya muchas gracias.

```
// consulta

private static final String SQL_SELECT_BY_ID = "SELECT EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, Dni, BirthDate, Email, Salary, EmployeeAddress,PostalCode, EmployeeHours, Turn, EducationLevel, Profession, Position, Sex, States, Boss, DistrictID  FROM Employee  WHERE EmployeeID = ?";


// seleccionar a un empleado por su id

public Employee selectEmployee(Employee employee) throws SQLException{

    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    try {

        connection = ConnectionDb.getConnection();
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_SELECT_BY_ID);
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, employee.getEmployeeId());
        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        

        //resultSet.absolute(1);  nos posicionamos en primer lugar si exite el usuario
        String firstName = resultSet.getString("FirstName");
        String lastName = resultSet.getString("LastName");
        String dni = resultSet.getString("Dni");
        String birthDate = resultSet.getString("BirthDate");
        String email = resultSet.getString("Email");
        double salary = resultSet.getDouble("Salary");
        String employeeAddress = resultSet.getString("EmployeeAddress");
        String postalCode = resultSet.getString("PostalCode");
        String employeeHours = resultSet.getString("EmployeeHours");
        String turn = resultSet.getString("Turn");
        String educationLevel = resultSet.getString("EducationLevel");
        String profession = resultSet.getString("Profession");
        String position = resultSet.getString("Position");
        String sex = resultSet.getString("Sex");
        String states = resultSet.getString("States");
        short boss = resultSet.getShort("Boss");
        int districtID = resultSet.getInt("DistrictID");

        employee.setFirstName(firstName);
        employee.setLastName(lastName);
        employee.setDni(dni);
        employee.setBirthDate(birthDate);
        employee.setEmail(email);
        employee.setSalary(salary);
        employee.setEmployeeAddress(employeeAddress);
        employee.setPostalCode(postalCode);
        employee.setEmployeeHours(employeeHours);
        employee.setTurn(turn);
        employee.setEducationLevel(educationLevel);
        employee.setProfession(profession);
        employee.setPosition(position);
        employee.setSex(sex);
        employee.setStates(states);
        employee.setBoss(boss);
        employee.setDistrictID(districtID);


    } catch (SQLException e) {
        ConnectionDb.processEception(e);
    } finally {
       if (resultSet != null && resultSet.isClosed() == false) {
            ConnectionDb.close(resultSet);
        }
        resultSet = null;
 
        if (preparedStatement != null && preparedStatement.isClosed() == false) {
            ConnectionDb.close(preparedStatement);
        }
        preparedStatement = null;

        if (connection != null && connection.isClosed() == false) {
            ConnectionDb.close(connection);
        }
        connection = null;

    }

    return employee;
}
```

Error que muestra:

> Error ***>>>El conjunto de resultados no tiene fila actual.
>
> code ***>>>0
>
> SQL state ***>>>null

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Según entiendo el uso de Resulset en otros lenguajes, para poder leerlo primero necesitas recorrer cada ítem, en tu set, en tu caso seria algo como  resultSet.next()

Answer (score 0):

Para asignar los campos del ResulSet tenes que meter esa asignación dentro de un while:

```
while (rs.next()) {
                employee.setFirstName = resultSet.getString("FirstName");
                //.....
            }
```